# The endpoint you have tried to access does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, api, mailgun

I send email batches via Mailgun's API from my Laravel app.

Up until August, the following code worked correctly. Since August, Mailgun has been returning the following error instead of providing the email batch statistics I'm requesting:

> The endpoint you have tried to access does not exist. Check if the
> domain matches the domain you have configure on Mailgun.

I've double-checked that both the domain and API secret key are correct.

Here's the code I'm using for this request which is resulting in the error:

```
try {

# Instantiate the client.
$mgClient = Mailgun::create(env('MAILGUN_SECRET'), 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/tags');
$domain = 'mail.mydomain.com'; // Yes I have this set to my actual domain in the code

$params = array(
    'tags' => 37, // Pass the batch ID (yes this matches a batch I've sent)
    'event' => array('delivered', 'failed', 'unsubscribed', 'complained')
);

# Issue the call to the client.
$result = $mgClient->tags()->stats($domain, $batch->id, $params);

foreach ( $result->getStats() as $stat ) {

    // I update my database with the results here

}

catch ( Exception $e ) {

    $file = fopen(storage_path() . '/logs/mailgun_batch_status_updates.log', 'a');
    fwrite($file, date('c') . "Error occured: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n");
    fclose($file);

}
```

I didn't make any updates to this code in August, so my assumption is that Mailgun changed their API endpoint or the parameters required for this request; however their API documentation does not show any changes from what I can tell.

I have also tried the following endpoint URLs, with the same results:

```
https://api.mailgun.net/tags
https://api.mailgun.net/mail.mydomain.com/tags (yes I used my actual mail domain)
https://api.mailgun.net/v4/tags
```

Not sure what changed in August, but I'd love to hear some ideas if anyone knows why this is happening since then.

Comment: The API endpoint for tags is `GET /<domain>/tags`, so you're missing the domain. - https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-tags.html#tags

Comment: What mailgun package are you using?

Comment: Thanks @aynber, I gave it a shot with my domain in the endpoint URL /mail.mydomain.com/tags but got the same result. My domain is being passed into the $mgClient->tags()->stats() call.

I'm using the mailgun-php package

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The error wasn't at all helpful in identifying that I was referring to a batch which had since been deleted from Mailgun.

The batch id no longer existed, so the request failed with

> The endpoint you have tried to access does not exist. Check if the domain matches the domain you have configure on Mailgun.